# remount /tmp for the current shell

Tags: linux, mount, path

I have a command which is hard-coded to use `/tmp` as its working directory.

`/tmp` is rather small, and the command is certain to fill it up, which will cause problems for other system processes.

I can't modify the command, so I would like to remount `/tmp` somewhere else, only visible to the current user/shell, without affecting other users/processes.

Is this possible?

Update: Discovered the command uses the `TMPDIR` variable which I can override, but still interested to know if there's a Linux user-space command I can use.

Comment: Would a `chroot` help?

Comment: you can mount /tmp in two places if your /tmp fs isn't incorporate in your root(/) fs, but you cannot umount /tmp with running processes and mounting in other place

Answer (score 14):

The unshare command can do pretty much what you are asking for:

```
unshare -m "$SHELL"
```

After that you can change any mounts you like locally to that shell only.

I recommend that any mount commands you run inside the unshared shell use the `-n` flag, because otherwise it will change `/etc/mtab` which will be visible to the entire system. You probably want `df` and `mount` commands run outside that shell to still show the correct file system mounted on `/tmp`.